# Effective field theories from QCD

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, effective-field-theory

Is there a way - at least formally - to derive theories like chiral perturbation theory or heavy baryon effective theory from QCD?

As an example: is it possible first to introduce the effective fields as auxiliary fields in the path integral and then to integrate out the fundamental fields?

Can one formulate a general method to derive effective fields like dressed quarks, meson scalars / vectors and nucleon spinors from fundamental quark and gluon fields?

I am more interested in the general approach, not in a detailed treatment of the effective theories.

Comment: The short answer is [one has tried](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05039),  and notably on the lattice approximation of the functional integral of QCD (LePage), but it has been a long, technical, and not fully gratifying story.

Comment: Table 1 of [Kronfeld 2002](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0205021).